# Disabling cufon styles for a specific >div>?

Tags: javascript, css, html, cufon

I am working on a wp theme that uses cufon for styling text. The problem is that now I am adding some stuff like a pricing table, which doesn't uses cufon, and the cufon styles are messing up those tables.

Is there a way to tell cufon not to style anything on that specific div tag where the pricing table is?

This is the cufon code that mess thing up:

```
Cufon.replace('.cufon, h1, h2, h3, h4', {
fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro Semibold'
});
```

Can I add a negative selector there?

Sorry if this is a silly question but I never really worked with cufon before.

Comment: http://reisio.com/examples/webfonts/

Answer (score 0):

```
Cufon.replace('.cufon, h1, h2, h3, h4:not(.myclass)', {
fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro Semibold'
});
```

Yep, was a silly question :P
It was easier than I though